# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I am having some troubles connecting my bluetooth headset on Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to connect it a couple of months ago, but probably something has changed after that. I have read answers to other questions but the solutions given there do not seem to work for my case.

Here is some terminal output which might be useful

```
System:    Host: lorenzo-K56CB Kernel: 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu1) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: ASUSTeK product: K56CB v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: K56CB v: 1.0 serial: N/A UEFI: American Megatrends v: K56CB.204 date: 01/25/2013
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-3537U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Ivy Bridge rev.9 cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9976
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 984 MHz 2: 903 MHz 3: 896 MHz 4: 886 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: i915,nouveau Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile version: 4.2 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-33-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.2
           IF: enp4s0f2 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 750.2GB (4.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: HGST_HTS541075A9 size: 750.2GB temp: 33C
           Optical-1: /dev/sr0 model: MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8C2 S rev: 1.00 dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 24x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running
Partition: ID-1: / size: 687G used: 31G (5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 54.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 45.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 2300
Info:      Processes: 309 Uptime: 22 min Memory: 2067.1/7863.0MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

This is the output of `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[    2.502377] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   77.277881] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   77.277897] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   77.277900] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   77.277901] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   77.277906] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   81.372099] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[   83.388105] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c45 tx timeout
[   85.404122] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c58 tx timeout
[   87.420084] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1004 tx timeout
[   95.107361] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   95.107363] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   95.107366] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

and this is the output of `sudo service bluetooth status`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-09-02 10:29:21 EDT; 29min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 895 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─895 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 02 10:29:19 lorenzo-K56CB systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 02 10:29:20 lorenzo-K56CB bluetoothd[895]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Sep 02 10:29:20 lorenzo-K56CB bluetoothd[895]: Starting SDP server
Sep 02 10:29:20 lorenzo-K56CB bluetoothd[895]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 02 10:29:21 lorenzo-K56CB systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

And this is the output of `dmesg | grep -i firm`

```
[    0.024000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.184169] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.817420] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
```

Here is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a total shutdown and then boot, edit the question to include results for `dmesg | grep -i firm`

Comment: Please post results for `lsusb`

Comment: Try a complete shutdown/power off and then boot, see if there is any change

Comment: @Jeremy31 there has been no change in the outputs you requested